# How to count the number of consecutive identical lines

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a file that looks like this:

```
2000
2000
2001
2001
2001
2001
2002
2002
```

I need a script to show me this:

```
2000 - 2
2001 - 4
2002 - 2
```

I prefer using sed or awk

Comment: This sounds like exactly what `uniq -c` was invented for ...

Comment: Oh nice I did not know that. Thanks!

Comment: `uniq -c file | sed -rn 's/ *([0-9]+) (.*)/\2 - \1/p'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is precisely what `uniq -c` does. From `man uniq`:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> Filter  adjacent  matching lines from INPUT (or standard input), writing to OUTPUT (or standard output).
>
> [ . . . ]
>
> -c, --count 
>              prefix lines by the number of occurrences

So with your example, we get:

```
$ uniq -c file
      2 2000
      4 2001
      2 2002
```

You can also write a little script if you prefer for some reason. For instance, with `awk`:

```
$ awk '{ count[$0]++ } END{ for(line in count){ print line,count[line] }}' file 
2000 2
2001 4
2002 2
```